# How to json_encode $GLOBALS?

Tags: php, json, global

I'm trying to debug a PHP application, and as a section of the debug process, I passed print_r($GLOBALS) through the AJAX request to my browser.  However, I'd prefer to see it in native JSON form because it comes out better in the browser.  I'm trying to use the following snippet of code:

```
json_encode($GLOBALS);
```

but I've found it returns bool(false).  The [JSON documentation](https://www.php.net/json_encode) says "Returns a JSON encoded string on success *or FALSE on failure.*"  But what about $GLOBALS makes it fail?  Is it the recursive $GLOBALS['GLOBALS']?

I was thinking as an alternative to loop over $GLOBALS and put that in an array, but that seems quite pointless when the point of json_encode is to encode an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon testing this myself, it appears json_encode() can't handle recursion such as what's provided in $GLOBALS['GLOBALS']... etc.

So a trick(?) you can do is:

```
json_encode(array_slice($GLOBALS, 1));
```

Which will skip past $GLOBALS['GLOBALS'] and continue encoding the rest of the array.

*EDIT: $GLOBALS['GLOBALS'] appears first for me when printing this array, but a better way is to find where $GLOBALS['GLOBALS'] appears and skip that element entirely.

Comment: int(6) - message is "Recursion detected".  I think you just got the number wrong for array_slice(), what you did slices one from the beginning.

Comment: You just missed a parameter, it should be json_encode(array_slice($GLOBALS, 0, -1));

Comment: @iggyvolz my goal was to skip the first element which is $GLOBALS['GLOBALS'] hence I made the offset argument 1 (which is the second parameter according to PHP docs) and continues for the rest of the array. But if it works for you then I can't complain.

Comment: I ended up using this: 
$globals_dump = $GLOBALS;
unset($globals_dump['GLOBALS']); // You might also have to unset($globals_dump['globals_dump']); depending on if you are in a function

Comment: @iggyvolz ah, well I guess that doesn't help either of us! :P Anyway, there are ways to just ignore that particular element anyway if you needed a fail-safe version (assuming you're working directly with $GLOBALS).

Comment: I proposed a way to implement this where the position of GLOBALS is not important.

Answer (score 3):

I propose a way where the position of GLOBALS is not important:

```
json_encode(array_intersect_key($GLOBALS,array_flip(array("_GET", "_POST", "_FILES", "_COOKIE"))));
```

or a better way:

```
$new_array = $GLOBALS;
$index = array_search('GLOBALS',array_keys($new_array));
json_encode(array_splice($new_array, $index, $index-1));
```

Comment: Doesn't this require you to hard-code all elements from $GLOBALS you want? What about global variables? http://codepad.org/VRTHyEtp

Comment: Yep. I did it now by just typing the index you would like to remove.

Comment: concept is the same but I like the implementation of the second snippet better than mine. +1

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `$GLOBALS` contains reference to itself results in an infinite recursion that `json_encode` can't handle because it exceeds the [maximum depth of 512](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and thus will return `false` by default.

The solution would be creating a copy of `$GLOBALS` without self-referencing, the function below references [superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) `_GET _POST _SERVER ..` only, assuming you don't use `$_` in your variables naming conventions:

```
function getEncodableGlobals()
{
    $g = [];

    foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => &$val)
    {
        if ($key[0] == '_')
        {
            $g[$key] = &$val;
        }
    }

    return $g;
}
```

Notice that `$g` doesn't hold copies but only references to variables, just like `$GLOBALS` does. If you wish to include all the variables in the global scope simply change the condition to exclude the troublesome reference:

```
...
    if ($key !== 'GLOBALS')
...
```

Now you can safely encode it:

```
json_encode(
    getEncodableGlobals()
);
```

---

You could also do it the `array_filter` way and copy the variables.

```
$encodableGlobals = array_filter($GLOBALS, function($key) {
    return $key !== 'GLOBALS';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` can't handle recursion such as what's provided in $GLOBALS['GLOBALS']... etc.

`JSON.stringify` is same!
you will retrieve error :
[image: JSON.stringify error because recursion]

So in php you can create a new variable, example `$globals` which holds an array of `$GLOBALS`.

And, unset the recursive `$globals['GLOBALS']`.

```
$globals = $GLOBALS;
unset($globals['GLOBALS']);
echo json_encode($globals);
```

And... Congrats!! Now you can `json_encode` `$GLOBALS` variable!