# json_encode doesn't works on array_splice return but works if called directly

Tags: php, arrays

My goal is very simple, I want to parse the `$GLOBALS` variable in JSON (to log it). According to this Stackoverflow post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23176085/1369579, I have to remove the recursive variable.

The following code works:

```php
<?php

$global_array = $GLOBALS;
$index = array_search('GLOBALS',array_keys($global_array));
$json = json_encode(array_splice($global_array, $index, $index-1));
var_dump($json);

?>
```

It returns `string(59) "{"GLOBALS":{"_GET":[],"_POST":[],"_COOKIE":[],"_FILES":[]}}"` (in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com)

But I have to use an intermediate variable to store the `array_splice` result. When I do this, I doesn't works:

```php
<?php

$global_array = $GLOBALS;
$index = array_search('GLOBALS',array_keys($global_array));
$splice_result = array_splice($global_array, $index, $index-1);
var_dump(json_encode($splice_result));

?>
```

The result is `bool(false)` and the `json_last_error_msg()` returns `Recursion detected`.

What the difference between the two versions? I really don't understand. For me `foo(bar())` is the exactly the same code than `$bar = bar(); foo($bar)`…

Comment: Why don't you use the solution in the question you linked to, with `array_slice()`?

Comment: `array_splice()` returns the elements that were removed, not the remainder of the array.

Comment: The problem is that `$global_array` contains an entry for itself, which is recursive.

Comment: Why do you use `$index-1` as the length to splice, instead of `1`?

Comment: Why do you need the intermediate variable in the first place?

Comment: If you put the code in a function, `$global_array` won't be global, so it won't be in `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks for you comments. I don't want to use `array_slice` because if someday 'GLOBALS' is not the first value in `$GLOBALS`, it will fail.

I need in intermediate variable because I want to log others variables and I build an associative array like this `['GLOBALS' => globalsWithoutGlobals(), 'otherVar' => 'otherValue', …]` and I want to encode it in JSON at the end. Maybe I could change my code to use the first version but the thing is I really don't understand the differences between the two versions. It's frustrating for me :)

Comment: I think GLOBALS can be expected always to be first, since all other global variables are necessarily created after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just understood my problem, the call of `array_splice` remove the `$GLOBALS` variable… but I still don't understand why.

I tried to put my code into a function, because I thought my problem was to put the code directly in the global scope:

```php
<?php

function globalWithoutGlobals() {
    $global_array = $GLOBALS;
    $index = array_search('GLOBALS',array_keys($global_array));
    array_splice($global_array, $index, 1);
    return $global_array;
}

var_dump(json_encode(globalWithoutGlobals()));
var_dump(json_encode(globalWithoutGlobals()));

/* returns
# First call: success, 
string(47) "{"_GET":[],"_POST":[],"_COOKIE":[],"_FILES":[]}"
# Second call : wtf ?!!
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: GLOBALS in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
*/
```

It's still very weird for me, the `$global_array` should be changed, not the `$GLOBALS`. To test this behaviour, I did the same thing on others arrays (with recursion too):

```php
<?php

// Looks like $GLOBALS (with recursive element)
$globals_array = ["foo" => "bar"];
$globals_array['GLOBALS'] = &$globals_array;

$copy = $globals_array;
$index = array_search('GLOBALS', array_keys($copy));
array_splice($copy, $index, 1);

var_dump($globals_array);
var_dump($copy);

/* return:
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["GLOBALS"]=>
  &array(2) {
    ["foo"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    ["GLOBALS"]=>
    *RECURSION*
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
*/
```

It returns the expected output, so why the behaviour is not the same with `$GLOBALS` ?

To resolve my issue, I changed my approach and I stopped used `array_splice`, instead I just do a naive implementation with a `foreach` on the `$GLOBALS`  and it works like expected:

```php
<?php

function globalWithoutGlobals() {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !== 'GLOBALS') {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(json_encode(globalWithoutGlobals()));
var_dump(json_encode(globalWithoutGlobals()));

/* it returns:
string(47) "{"_GET":[],"_POST":[],"_COOKIE":[],"_FILES":[]}"
string(47) "{"_GET":[],"_POST":[],"_COOKIE":[],"_FILES":[]}"
*/
```

If someone know why the behaviour is different between my two first examples above. I'm curious to understand

Comment: You can use `array_slice($GLOBALS, 0, $index, true) + array_slice($GLOBALS, $index + 1, true)` instead of the loop.